# Footnote at the end of an environment

Tags: footnotes

I want my footnotes to appear at the end of my enumerate environment, rather than at the bottom of the page. How would I change the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1 \footnotemark[1]
    \item Item 2 \footnotemark[1]
    \item Item 3 \footnotemark[2]
    \item Item 4
    \footnotetext[1]{Complete}
    \footnotetext[2]{Requires selection from existing algorithms}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

to result in this:

[image: Footnote at the end of an enumerate]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in a `minipage`.  Of course, `minipage` invocation of `\footnotetext` will then use letters rather than numbers that are otherwise associated with page footnotes, unless changed, as suggested by Mico, with `\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}` inside the `minipage`.

However, note that the `minipage` footnotes are not part of the globally indexed footnote sequence, but in fact restart their own numbering with each `minipage`.

EDITED to use actual `\footnote`s rather than just `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1 \footnote{Complete}
    \item Item 2 \footnotemark[1]
    \item Item 3 \footnote{Requires selection from existing algorithms}
    \item Item 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's still a minor issue with the example: you have 1-->a, 2-->b.

Comment: Adding the instruction `\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}` -- insert it right after `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` -- will revert to arabic numerals for minipage footnotes.

Comment: @Mico Yes, though I guess the point I was trying to make is that the footnotes, even with your change, would not be part of the running index of page footnotes (it is for this reason that they are made with letters, to avoid the confusion)

Answer (score 1):

This augments [Steven B. Segletes's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes) answer in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351179/73051).

Using an enumerate in a minipage gave me quite a few problems, especially with long lists with lots of text in sub items. I found that moving only the `\footnotetext` to the minipage, instead of the entire `enumerate` environment solved the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1 \footnotemark[1]
        \item Item 2 \footnotemark[1]
        \item Item 3 \footnotemark[2]
        \item Item 4
    \end{enumerate}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \footnotetext[1]{Complete}
        \footnotetext[2]{Requires selection from existing algorithms}
    \end{minipage}
    \bigskip

    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]